# Communication with a web relay (Relay connected via ethernet) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, network-programming

I am trying to communicate to a web relay (relay connected to ethernet). The address of the relay is 192.168.1.153 port 80. I need to send an HTTP `GET` request to know is state:

```
GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==
```

I have written this code:

```pascal
var
  get_url, Reponse: string;
  resp: TStringStream;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  CR, LF: char;
begin
  CR := chr(13);
  LF := chr(10);
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  resp := TStringStream.Create;
  IdHTTP.Request.Host := '192.168.1.153:80';
  IdHTTP.Request.Username := 'admin'; // User
  IdHTTP.Request.Password := 'webrelay'; // Password
  IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := false; //Auth. BASIC
  try
    get_url := 'GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1' + CR + LF +
      'Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==' + CR + LF + CR + LF;
    memoGET.Text := IdHTTP.Get(get_url);
```

I have an error with `IdHTTP.Get()` because the port number seems to be unknown. I have tried to write `IdHTTP.Request.Port:=80` but it doesn't work.

---

**Update:** Unfortunatly I still can't get it working with `TIdHTTP`. I get this error:

> project Testeur_Webrelay.exe has rise the exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException with message '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.

I have an example which works, written in VB, but I am not able to translate it to Delphi, as VB is like an alien language for me:

```vb
'Connect to webrelay
port = Convert.ToInt32(portTextBox.Text)
tcpClient.Connect(addressTextBox.Text.ToString(), port)

If tcpClient.Connected Then

  'Create a network stream object
  Dim netStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

  'If we can read and write to the stream then do so
  If netStream.CanWrite And netStream.CanRead Then

    'Send the on command to webrelay
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /state.xml?noReply=0 HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    'Get the response from webrelay
    Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    netStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    'Parse the response and update the webrelay state and input text boxes
    Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

It's true that 'bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==' is for 'none:webrelay' and not admin:webrelay'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TIdHTTP` the wrong way. Use it like this instead:

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    // the username encoded in 'bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==' is 'none' instead of 'admin'... 
    IdHTTP.Request.Username := 'none'; //'admin'; // User
    IdHTTP.Request.Password := 'webrelay'; // Password
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := true; //Auth. BASIC
    memoGET.Text := IdHTTP.Get('http://192.168.1.153/state.xml');
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work. I get this error: project Testeur_Webrelay.exe has rise the exeption class EIdHTTPProtocolException with message ''. I have an example which work, written in VB, but I am not really able to translate it in Delphi as VB is like alien language for me:

Comment: `TIdHTTP` handles everything the VB code is doing. You are getting an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception because the server is sending back an HTTP error that happens to contain XML as its content. You need to find out why the server is sending an error, we can't diagnose that for you since you haven't provided any useful details for troubleshooting. What is the actual error code that is being sent? It is in the exception's `ErrorCode` property, as well as in the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property. What does the rest of the error XML say? It likely tells you why the server failed the request.